# POST call to Intercom API using httparty does not work because the "Query body must contain a query hash"

Tags: ruby, api, httparty, intercom

I want to use httparty to make a POST call to the Intercom API in order to search for conversations following certain criteria. 
I tested first in Postman and it works fine (see screenshot on the following link) 
[API call inside Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNHGA.png)
However, when I want to make this API call in ruby using the httparty gem, it does not work. 
I used the following code:

```
  headers: {
      "Content-Type":  "application/json",
      Authorization: "Bearer {{value of the token}}",
      Accept: "application/json",
  },
  query: {
      "field": "updated_at",
      "operator": ">",
      "value": 1592248820
  }
}

results = HTTParty.post('https://api.intercom.io/conversations/search', options)
```

It returns me the following error:

```
{"type":"error.list","request_id":"0001t1gne3j7pscoq2n0","errors":[{"code":"invalid_query","message":"Query body must contain a query hash"}]}
```

It is really strange because I tested this syntax for another POST call to the Intercom API using exactly the same syntax and it worked fine. See below:

```
  headers: {
      "Content-Type":  "application/json",
      Authorization: "Bearer {{value of the token}}",
      Accept: "application/json",
  },
  query: {
        "email": "wash@serenity.io",
        "name": "Hoban Washburn",
        "role": "user"
  }
}

results = HTTParty.post('https://api.intercom.io/contacts', options)
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that the query has to be in the body of the call, so I'd suggest trying...

```
  headers: {
      "Content-Type":  "application/json",
      Authorization: "Bearer {{value of the token}}",
      Accept: "application/json",
  },
  body: {
    query: {
        "field": "updated_at",
        "operator": ">",
        "value": 1592248820
    }
  }
}
```

That also matches your Postman call better.

Comment: Hey Steve, 
Thanks a lot for your suggestion. 
I tested what you suggested and I now get the following error: 
```{"status":400,"error":"There was a problem in the JSON you submitted [ea3162e278ef4068cca02a4dc3b303c5]: Empty input () at line 1, column 1 [parse.c:979] in 'query%5Bfield%5D=updated_at&query%5Boperator%5D=%3E&query%5Bvalue%5D=1592248820"}
```